# pausing execution for 1 second

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an IBAction which starts a number of timers.

I would like to have a second or a pause for a certain time. How can I pause execution?

I know of the `[self performSelector:@selector(someMEthod:) withObject:someObject afterDelay:1.0];`

but how can I just cause a delay without calling anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `sleep()` or `+[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` but please don't do that on the main thread. Pausing execution of the main thread means your app's UI will be blocked for that time and appear to the user as if it had crashed. If you blocked the main thread for more than a few seconds, Apple's watchdog timer would kill your app instantly.

See this blog post by Jeff LaMarche for more on this issue: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/psa-respect-main-thread.html

Comment: Cool. Yeah I will put the sleep() in the IBAction which starts the timer. Does sleep() take an argument? or where do I set the time to sleep. I have a number of IBActions which start when a button is pressed. These actions each start a timer, I want a gap between timers starts. Doing it this way wont block the main execution.

Comment: What makes you think that? A tap action on a button will be called on the main thread. Just don't do it.

Comment: I never explained properly. I link a number of IBActions to the same UIButton. each IBAction calls another function which starts a timer. At the moment these timers start immediately after one another, how can I put a small delay in between them? can the following be used with a delay? countdownTimer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.10 target: self selector: @selector(handleTimer) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];  ?

Comment: What if I call the next timer from within a running timer? That will get messy right? Also is an NSTimer considered an actual thread, a separate execution process? thanks

Comment: Yes, that's how you should do it. Timers are runloop-based, so they do not run on a separate thread.

Comment: So Timers dont block the main thread, once they are executed, started?

Comment: Rather than saying "Here's how to do it, now don't do it," just don't tell people how to do things they shouldn't do.

Comment: @Chris - I think you missed the point. And that way of thinking "just don't tell people how to do things they shouldn't do" is tunnel visioned.

Comment: @alJaree - I didn't miss the point. You should NOT "just cause a delay" in your user experience, that's not something that either the iOS or Mac user experience supports - it takes control away from the user.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to cause a delay without calling anything.  It's bad for the UI, and does not fit Cocoa Touch's event driven paradigm.

Cut the routine in which you want to pause into (at least) two parts/halves.  Have the first half set up a delayed call to the second half (perform selector with delay, timer, queue, etc.) and then return to the main loop.  The OS will call the second part, later, after potentially doing useful stuff in the mean time (giving the user a responsive UI or saving battery life, catching up with background email, etc.)

You may have to learn how to save state between parts (loop variables, etc.), something that some new programmers seem to miss in their learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sleep(int_No_of_Sec); // eg. sleep(1);